# Manually refresh output cache in IIS7

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, outputcache

Problem description: 
On our website we use standard asp cache with duration set to 5h.

It works fine, but sometimes the publisher add some special content that need to be showed impatiently on many different sub-pages (example some promoted article).

That's what I need to do it's easy to use page like this:

mydomain.com/admin/clear-all-website-output-cache.aspx.

I want to clear SERVER SIDE CACHE.

Thanks for help.

we use: IIS7, ASP.net 3.5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [cache dependency](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpresponse.addcachedependency.aspx) on some file, the cache will expire when the file changed.

Answer (score 3):

See this ServerFault question: [Will an IIS reset force cached items to be resent?](https://serverfault.com/questions/176943)

This says that you need to use IISRESET (or reset IIS any other way) to do it.

I assume recycling the application pool of the application will have the same effect. It's a good practice to have one application pool per application, so, this should be less problematic than resetting IIS if there are other critical applications.

If your app pool is shared with other applications, create a new one, and change the app pool in the application properties to the new pool. Likely will have a similar effect.

BTW, I do not think stopping and starting the website (assuming likely the app has its own website) will have a similar effect, as it will not stop the process instance that holds the cache, which is represented by app pool. Not 100% sure though.